# Python: Returning key of dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

If i have a list of words:

```
list_of_words = ['great','debate','stronger']
```

And a dictionary:

```
dictionary = {'candidate1':['corruption','election'],'candidate2': ['lady','draintheswamp','stronger','debate'],'candidate3':['healthcare','oil']}
```

I have to create a function that detects the producer of the list of words.

In the example above: 'Candidate2' is the most likely producer of list_of_words

Please don't import any modules . Efficiency is not the main concern here.

Comment: Why can you not import any modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate through the dictionary items and check if any of the items are inside the value for a given key, if so, append in a list `cand` that holds the candidates for which the condition holds.

Then, you return the first candidate if the length of the list is one and, if not, you return `None`.

In code, this looks like this:

```
def find_candidate():
    cand = []
    for i,j in dictionary.items():
        if any(v in j for v in list_of_words):
            cand.append(i)
    return cand[0] if len(cand) == 1 else None
```

and when called, it returns candidate 2:

```
find_candidate()
'candidate2'
```

Alternatively, the list creation can be done with a comprehension:

```
def find_candidate():
    c = [k for k, j in dictionary.items() if any(v in j for v in list_of_words)]
    return c[0] if len(c) == 1 else None
```

Comment: Question for the OP: Given the list_of_words=['a','b','c'] and the dictionary={'candidate1':['a','b'], 'candidate2':['a']} should it return 'candidate1'? If so, this solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the nature of the question I thought it could be useful to know the number of candidates that use each word in the list. This is how I would approach it:

```
def get_candidate(list_of_words, candidates):
    stats={}
    for word in list_of_words:
        stats[word] = []
        for candidate, candidate_words in candidates.items():
            if word in candidate_words:
                stats[word].append(candidate)

    return stats

list_of_words=['a','b','c','d']
candidates={'candidate1':['a','b','c'], 'candidate2':['b','c'], 'candidate3':['c','d']}

print(get_candidate(list_of_words, candidates))
```

This would print out:

```
{
 'a': ['candidate1'], 
 'c': ['candidate3', 'candidate2', 'candidate1'], 
 'b': ['candidate2', 'candidate1'], 
 'd': ['candidate3']
}
```

Here we can see that candidate1 is the only one to use word 'a' and candidate3 the only one to use 'd'.
This might not be the exact solution the OP was looking for, but I think it might help ;)